# Placeholder Text Not visible in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am having difficulty in getting to display the placeholder text in IE 11 and FireFox. It works fine in chrome. I have include the HTML for just 2 fields.

HTML

```
<input type="email" class="form-control CustomerNumber_Box" id="inputEmail" placeholder="DOMAIN \ NETWORK ID">

<input type="password" class="form-control CustomerNumber_Box" id="inputEmail" placeholder="PASSWORD">
```

CSS

```
.CustomerNumber_Box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #97999B;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 27px 0;
  color: #97999b;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 441px;
  position: relative;
  left: 14px;
  top: -5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

FireFox
[image: Screenshot of Firefox]
[image: Screenshot of Chrome]

It works with the below CSS when i adjust the height and padding

Updated CSS:

```
.CustomerNumber_Box {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $tooltip_border;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 9px 0;
    color: $black;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 441px;
    position: relative;
    left: 14px;
    top: -5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 57px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it with the element declared? E.g.

```
<font color='"#FF0000"'>input</font>:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #A1A1A1;
}
```

I don't have IE 11, so not able to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stylize the *`placeholder`* text then you should follow all possible the **browser prefixes** for that as:

### Code Snippet

```css
.CustomerNumber_Box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #97999B;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 27px 0;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 441px;
  position: relative;
  left: 14px;
  top: -5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.CustomerNumber_Box::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #909090;
}
.CustomerNumber_Box:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #909090;
}
.CustomerNumber_Box::-webkit-placeholder {
  color: #909090;
}
.CustomerNumber_Box::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #909090;
}
.CustomerNumber_Box:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #909090;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control CustomerNumber_Box" id="inputEmail" placeholder="DOMAIN \ NETWORK ID">

<input type="password" class="form-control CustomerNumber_Box" id="inputEmail" placeholder="PASSWORD">
```

Comment: Doesnt work, but when I reduce the padding then it seems to work, also if I give it a height it seems to work

Comment: there must be something else in your code as this snippet working perfectly fine, even I'm using this in my several projects without any glitch.